# Sort numbers 1-10 stored as their spelling in a arraylist in java

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I have arraylist of string as follows

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("one");
list.add("ten");
list.add("six");
list.add("two");
```

output after sorting should be
one, two, six, ten

Comment: I see the following approach: implement a `Comparator<String>`, add a parsing logic there String -> int, and simply compare ints

Comment: You dropped (homework?) requirements. What have you tried to solve the problem?

Comment: `Collections.sort` should work?

Comment: @ycf-l 's solution is your best bet. It is most efficient after all because of Hashing.

Comment: @Jarrod: This is clearly not a duplicate of *any* of those questions. Please spend more time choosing (accurate) duplicates in future...

Answer (score 1):

You can order based in values of a Map for example:

```
Map<String, Integer> numbers = new HashMap<>();
numbers.put("one", 1);
numbers.put("two", 2);
numbers.put("three", 3);
numbers.put("four", 4);
numbers.put("five", 5);
numbers.put("six", 6);
numbers.put("seven", 7);
numbers.put("height", 8);
numbers.put("nine", 9);
numbers.put("ten", 10);

List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("one");
list.add("ten");
list.add("six");
list.add("two");

Collections.sort(list, (o1, o2) -> {
    return numbers.get(o1) - numbers.get(o2);
});
System.out.println(list);
```

**Output**

```
[one, two, six, ten]
```

Comment: mmm, down-votes and delete why ? can you explain please?

Comment: Jarrod likes to identify duplicates and then downvote all people daring to answer that duplicated thing. Even when he puts up 4 dups and none of them matches the question asked here. I see what I can do about this.

Comment: @GhostCat The fair, always the fair :)

Comment: @YCF_L Just for information, I have upvoted your answer after you were dowvoted and just after it someone has still downvoted you.

Comment: i want to be all the same @davidxxx :)

Comment: For the record: I also voted for closing - for being too broad/unclear. Simply because the op only posted requirements but did not show any effort to solve the problem himself. So don't expect me to participate in the reopen vote. I have no problem to re-open wrong dup closes (I actually did that twice during the last weeks), but not today.

Comment: @GhostCat Thank you for these details. It is true that some questions don't deserve answers as it is a way to feed vampires and encourage them to come back. But when there is really no fresh Java questions, I make too often the mistake to answer. I have to work on it :)

Answer (score 1):

Quick and short solution:

```
List<String> allNumbers = Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten");
Collections.sort(list, (i1, i2) -> allNumbers.indexOf(i1) - allNumbers.indexOf(i2));
```

Use a `HashMap` with indexed string keys for a faster algorithm (if you have 10 values, there's no difference anyway).

Answer (score 1):

Java doesn't provide an out of box way to sort String in this ways.

You could use a Comparator that compare the value of two String according to this rule.

An effective way would be to create in the `Comparator` class  with all String that you want to sort and use the index of the element to know its order.

For example :

```
public class MyNumberInStringComparator implements Comparator<String> {

    private static List<String> numbers = Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three");             


    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        return Integer.compare(numbers.indexOf(o1),numbers.indexOf(o2));
    }

}
```